# JavaScript toggle behavior not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple toggle button with JavaScript and **the `else` part is not working**. The lamp is just turning on and then it stops working. How do I solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="toggleBulb()">Turn on/off</button>

<img style="margin-left:43%;border:1px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);padding:
20px;" id='light' src='../Media/lighton.gif'>

<script>
function toggleBulb() {
    var doc = document.getElementById('light')
    if (doc.src == '../Media/lightoff.gif') {
        doc.src = '../Media/lighton.gif'
    } else if (doc.src == '../Media/lighton.gif') {
        doc.src = '../Media/lightoff.gif'
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because the `src` isn't ever the value `'../Media/lighton.gif'`. The real value is interpreted as the full path, as such none of your conditions will be hit.

Comment: You should check whether the src contains the "lightoff.gif" or the "lighton.gif" image. you can use indexOf to achieve that. that's because the src will always return the full path rather than the relative path

Comment: And, once you've corrected that, you don't need the `else if()`, just an `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the difference between a property and an attribute.  The attribute is the text in the HTML that you can see in the markup, but this is not always the same as the property by the same name.  In this case, the property `src` is the evaluated URL represented by the `src` attribute.  You'll notice that in my demo, I have a `src` attribute that begins with `//`, which tells the browser to use the current page's protocol for this resource, matching the page.  The calculated property has `https://` for the protocol because this stackoverflow page has an SSL installed.  In the end, you should use [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) when comparing attributes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="toggleBulb()">Turn on/off</button>

<img style="margin-left:43%;border:1px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);padding: 
20px;" id='light' src='//placehold.it/100/FF0/000?text=ON'>

<script>
function toggleBulb() {
    var doc = document.getElementById('light');
    if (doc.getAttribute('src') == '//placehold.it/100/000/FFF?text=OFF') {
        doc.src = '//placehold.it/100/FF0/000?text=ON'
    } else if (doc.getAttribute('src') == '//placehold.it/100/FF0/000?text=ON') {
        doc.src = '//placehold.it/100/000/FFF?text=OFF'
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, I' recommend this instead as `.getAttribute('src')` will give the exact value OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks Man! Working Well!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment the `src` is the full path on this file based on the website it's on. Instead one other you could do is check if the `src` ends with the string you are looking for:

```
function toggleBulb() {
    var doc = document.getElementById('light')
    if (doc.src.endsWith('/Media/lightoff.gif')) {
        doc.src = '../Media/lighton.gif'
    } else if (doc.src.endsWith('/Media/lighton.gif')) {
        doc.src = '../Media/lightoff.gif'
    }
}
```

Or you could check/set the full paths instead. Also not the `else if` can be made into just an `else`, unless you are planning to add more to that logic.

Comment: Really don't need the `else if()`. Just an `else` will do.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Just added that as a note.

Comment: Just a note: old browsers (<= IE11) don't support endswith, you can use lodash or underscore.js implementations or various other alternatives for it if compatibility is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your are checking the `src` property for an exact match, but that property will always return the full URL, and you aren't testing against full URLs, so you'll never get a match.

However, unlike the other answers, it's best to use **[`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** to check the image source string to see if it contains a sub-string. Then it won't matter which value you get for the source (`src` attribute or full path). `.indexOf()` returns the index position of the substring or -1 if it can't be found.

Also, the `if/then` can be simplified using JavaScript's **[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="toggleBulb()">Turn on/off</button>

<img style="margin-left:43%;border:1px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);padding: 
20px;" id='light' src='//placehold.it/100/FF0/000?text=ON'>

<script>
function toggleBulb() {
    var doc = document.getElementById('light');
    // If the source contains "lightoff", set it to "lighton", otherwise set it to "lightoff"
    doc.src =  doc.src.indexOf('../Media/lightoff.gif') > -1 ? "../Media/lighton.gif" : doc.src;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because we got one of those users who down-votes everything because they thing it's a bad question, despite if the answers are good or not (`+1`). Unfortunately these types of users that misuse down-votes like that are more common then they should be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write full code at each and every place where you are comparing the images. Also `doc.src` returns  A String, representing the URL of the image, including the protocol  like- (http:///now here the full path of image.
if you code are running on localhost then file:///now here the full path of image.) I have added this in the code and it'll run correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="toggleBulb()">Turn on/off</button>

<img style="margin-left:43%;border:1px solid rgb(50, 50, 50);padding: 20px;" id='light' src='**insert your full path of image here**'>

<script>
function toggleBulb() {
    var doc = document.getElementById('light');


   if (doc.src== "file:///insert your full path of image here") 
    {
       doc.src='insert your full path of image here';

    } 
    else if (doc.src == "file:///insert your full path of image here") {
        doc.src='full path of image here';

    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```